# Agregar Atributo contenidos en un arreglo a una colección de laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy intentando agregar un atributo a una colección de Laravel para luego mostrar esos datos en la vista, utilizando un @foreach. 
Los datos que quiero agregar los tengo en un arreglo, y el problema que tengo es que estoy agregando el arreglo con la función map pero me añade el indice del arreglo y necesito es el valor no el indice.

```
 $equip->map(function($equipo,$dias_prestamos){
           $equipo->cantidad = $dias_prestamos; 

    });
```

Aquí muestro lo que obtengo y lo que tengo en el arreglo:

[image: dd de la colección obtenida y del arreglo que empleo]

En este ejemplo tengo solo un equipo seleccionado. Pero pueden existir n cantidad de equipos en la colección y n cantidad de elementos en el arreglo.

Comment: Hola Nubia. Podrías cambiar la imagen del response por un bloque de código por favor? Resulta más cómodo leerlo de esa forma. También te recomiendo detallar tu pregunta para aclarar de qué arreglo estamos hablando, algunas líneas antes de tu map también ayudarían para entender qué es lo que quieres manejar ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás pasando los parámetros en el lugar incorrecto, aunque no conocemos tu array, pero asumo que los índices son números consecutivos (iniciando en 0), para lo cual deberías apoyarte en use para que map pueda hacer uso de dicho arreglo:

```
$myArray = [10, 20, 30, 60];
// aquí asumo que cada valor del array que deseo agregar a un elemento
// de la colección, va en el mismo orden que los elementos de esta


$newCollection = $equip->map(function($item, $key) use ($myArray) {
    $item->cantidad = $myArray[$key]; 
});
```

Por favor revisa la documentación del método map: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-map

Comment: Efectivamente en el arregle  tengo los valores en las misma posiciones que los elementos de la colección. 
Ya he había chequeado la documentación pero seguía confundida.  
Tu respuesta me ayudo mucho . mil gracias de verdad.

Comment: Listo, gracias.